# React - textarea does not re-focus after form submission

Tags: reactjs, antd

Basically the title. Once user submits the form, the textarea cursor does not re-focus. Why?

**Parent.tsx**

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'antd';

export const Parent = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement | null>(null);

  const onSubmit = useCallback(
    async (values: any) => {
      if (values) {
        form.resetFields(['question']);
        inputRef.current?.focus();
      }
    },
    [form]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }, [inputRef]);

  return <Child onSubmit={onSubmit} form={form} ref={inputRef} />;
};
```

**Child.tsx**

```
import { Input, Button, FormInstance, Form } from 'antd';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
const { TextArea } = Input;

type Props = {
  onSubmit: (values: any) => void;
  form: FormInstance<any>;
};

export type Ref = HTMLTextAreaElement;

export const Child = forwardRef<Ref, Props>(
  ({ onSubmit, form }, ref) => {

    return (
      <Form onFinish={onSubmit} form={form} >
        <Form.Item
          name="question"
          shouldUpdate
          rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please enter a query.' }]}
        >
          <TextArea
            placeholder="Search..."
            autoSize
            bordered={false}
            ref={ref}
          />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item shouldUpdate>
          {({ getFieldValue }) => (
            <Button
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              disabled={
                !getFieldValue('question')?.trim().length ||
                !!form.getFieldsError().filter(({ errors }) => errors.length)
                  .length
              }
              icon={<StyledSendOutlined />}
            />
          )}
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add `autoFocus` to TextArea and it worked. No refs needed.

```
<TextArea
 placeholder="Search..."
 autoSize
 autoFocus
 bordered={false}
/>
```